# MySQL--possible to use LIKE and IN together...or IN with FULLTEXT?

Tags: mysql

Trying to do this...I have a column `type_style` possible values would be `2 Story,Beach House` or `Contemporary,2 Story` Im trying to use `type_style` as a search query, but values for the search would be `2 Story`, `Beach House`, `Contemporary`. Each row could be a combination of any of the type_style's. My original idea was to do

```
WHERE `type_style` LIKE '%contemporary%'
```

Which would work fine if the user could only select one style, the client wants to have the users be able to select more than one style, so how would I go about doing this? The database is updated nightly from the state MLS, so aside from assigning a FULLTEXT index or something I cant change the way the `type_style` column is setup, any ideas? Any way to combine the IN statement and a LIKE-style comparision? Im pretty sure I could do something like

```
WHERE 
MATCH (`type_style`) AGAINST ('*2 story*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR
MATCH(`type_style`) AGAINST ('*contemporary*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But this would stand to be a very large query as there are about 20 style types....any other way to do this????

Comment: It does not quite make sense to me that you require the `LIKE` operator in the first place. It seems as if you are using type_style as a discrete class of possibilities. If you were able to change like to equality then all your problems would go away as you could you use a proper `IN` query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have table with `type_styles`:

1. 2 story
2. contemporary
3. beach house

third table connecting:

`record_is`, `style_id`

search on third table, so you can have multiple answers

if combine text '2 story, contemporary' is needed use `CONCAT_GROUP`